# PredictionIO Mavericks installation

Tags: prediction, predictionio

I am using official install guide:
http://docs.prediction.io/0.8.0/install/install-sourcecode.html

```
$ git clone https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO.git
$ cd PredictionIO
$ ./make-distribution.sh
```

after typing those commands I got error:

```
[warn] Class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class java.lang.AutoCloseable not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] 
[error]      while compiling: /Users/voldemar/tmp/PredictionIO/data/src/main/scala/storage/elasticsearch/ESEngineInstances.scala
[error]         during phase: typer
[error]      library version: version 2.10.4
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.4
```

Please, advise me solution for installation PredictionIO on OSX system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved with installation of JDK 7.